# MYSQL GROUP BY multiple and get count

Tags: mysql

I would like to group products by their associated quoteId and get only the unique products from a table like below:

[image]

On top of doing this I would like to add a column that shows the count of how many of that product was in the associated quote similar to the following:

[image]

This is beyond my MYSQL skills and I was wondering if I could get a hand figuring out what would I have to do for a query to achieve this?

Comment: GROUP BY ____ means you want to have one result row per ____. In your case this is the productId/quoteId pairs. Hence: `GROUP BY productId, quoteId`. Per group you want the number of records, which is `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: This is just for a little side project so there is no need to waste money hiring someone. Also, I was being nice in my wording. I'm actually just exhausted and needed someone to help me out with a brain fart. I had it right but for some reason had single quotes around each of my selects like an idiot. Not sure why people come on a forum meant to help people and not help? I guess some people have too much time on their hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation function count() and group by  productid, quoteid

```
select productid, quoteid, count(*)
from my_table  
group by productid, quoteid
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following ...

```
SELECT
    productid, quoteid, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    product
GROUP BY
    productid, quoteid
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```